# How can I add user input to a database and display it in a ListFragment?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments

I'm using an SQLite db and a cursor adapter to create the listview in my fragment. I have a helper class to create the initial table here:

```
TaskDatabase(Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    updateDB(db,0, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    updateDB(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}

private void updateDB(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    if(oldVersion < 2 ){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TASK("
                +"_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                +"NAME TEXT, "
                +"DESCRIPTION TEXT);");
        insertTask(db, "get milk");
        insertTask(db, "walk dog");
    }
}
```

Then in my fragment, I create the SQLitedb object, cursor, and set the adapter. However, for some reason, the initial items in the DB aren't appearing in my listview when I run the app.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
        SQLiteOpenHelper taskDbHelper = new TaskDatabase(getActivity());
        db = taskDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query("TASK",
                new String[]{"_id", "NAME"},
                null,null,null,null,null);
        CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cursor,
                new String[]{"NAME"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    } catch (SQLiteException e){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Last is my quicAdd method, it's a button that retrieves the user's input from an edittext box. I want to feed that into the DB and display it in the listfragment.

```
public void onQuickAdd(View v){
    EditText button = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quick_add);
    String task = button.getText().toString();
    if(task.length() < 1){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter a task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }


    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(button.getWindowToken(), 0);
    button.setText(new char[] {}, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Is `insertTask` a function you wrote?

Comment: can you add all the layout and java files here to debug?